# Debian 10 Very Slow Upload

Tags: debian, networking, drivers

I installed a fresh install of Debian 10 buster on my z97x system. My home connection is **300Mbps** download and **15Mbps** upload. I used speedtest to measure this. Selecting the same server using speedtest-cli on my Debian 10 install I get 299Mbps download and only **3.29Mbps** upload.

The upload speed is super slow. I have checked the cables and switches. Direct connecting the cable to the router makes no different. I had this issue on another Debian 10 server same exact upload and download with a realtek ethernet port on the motherboard - switching to a PCIE ethernet fixes this.

Running windows on this same machine has the correct 15Mbps upload so it leads me to believe there is something going on with Debian 10 and the drivers. I can just install a PCI E nic but I would rather use the port built into this motherboard as the case has no PCI slots.

***Motherboard: GA-Z97X-UD3H-BK***

```
lspci output
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V
```

**EDIT #1**
I have tried installing the drivers manually following these instructions: https://downloadmirror.intel.com/15817/eng/readme.txt to the best of my knowledge. The issue still persists!

I tried this too: https://superuser.com/questions/624484/installing-debian-7-1-using-net-install-with-intel-i217-v

Is there any other information I can gather to help fix this issue?

Comment: have you tried using `ethtool` to, e.g., set the speed to 1000 full-duplex, and turn off auto-negotiation?  i've also read that disabling wake-on-lan can help with this NIC.   please add the output of `ethtool eth0` (or whatever your NIC's device name is) to your question.

Comment: Thanks @cas turning off auto-negotiation solved my issue. put it as an answer and ill mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning off auto-negotiation with `ethtool`.  e.g. if your NIC is `eth0`:

```
ethtool -s autoneg off eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
root@vps92153:~# ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off
root@vps92153:~# speedtest
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from LLC IT-service (185.65.202.40)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Orange Business Services, Russia & CIS (Moscow) [1.61 km]: 9.263 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 752.64 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 4.08 Mbit/s
```