# Debian 10 Upload too Slow

Tags: debian, networking, upload

Greetings I already found this Question here ([Debian 10 Very Slow Upload](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536555/debian-10-very-slow-upload/543926#543926)) but it didnt resolved my issue. For my Network the Uploadspeed is too slow.
So I hope someone can help me please.

```
cat /etc/debian_version
10.1
ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP AUI BNC MII FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes

speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Internetprovider (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx)... (changed by Caaruzo)
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Company (City) [6.09 km]: 12.472 ms (changed by Caaruzo)
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 91.21 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 3.70 Mbit/s
```

3.70 Mbit/s is very slow. when i try another machine on same network i get 34.05 Mbit/s

Does someone have an idea what could cause this issue? I am Using onboard LAN. Mainboard is A320M-DGS

done iperf3 test now

```
    iperf3 -c 192.168.178.32
Connecting to host 192.168.178.32, port 5201
[  5] local 192.168.178.40 port 43810 connected to 192.168.178.32 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   114 MBytes   952 Mbits/sec    0   3.01 MBytes
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec    0   3.01 MBytes
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   112 MBytes   943 Mbits/sec    0   3.01 MBytes
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   111 MBytes   934 Mbits/sec    0   3.01 MBytes
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec    0   3.01 MBytes
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec    0   3.01 MBytes
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec    0   3.01 MBytes
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec    0   3.01 MBytes
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec    0   3.01 MBytes
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   111 MBytes   935 Mbits/sec    0   3.01 MBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   938 Mbits/sec    0             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.04  sec  1.09 GBytes   934 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Ive also recognized, it happens to all my machines that run under Debian 10.1. Also Virtual ones. With machines with Version 9.11 this problem don't exist.

Comment: from your output it doesn't look like you turned auto-negotiation off like the previous question's answer suggests.

Comment: Speedtest tests your connectivity to the outside. We wont be able to guess what is your connectivity problems and the question is VERY scant on details. It would be much more useful doing some debug than writing "help me please"; but at the end of the day debugging networking problems is not the aim of this group. I would guess having auto negotiation off is already part of some debugging.

Comment: Try measuring performance from a local computer, you could use `iperf3` to do this.

Comment: Auto-negotiation is off, sorry i just copy and pasted the wrong lines by an accidient. Also added the output of iperf3. Hope someone knows a solution pls.